# Progress bar for pass-through query

Tags: sql, database, vba, ms-access

I have a pass-through query and it takes more than 4 minutes to get the results back. The query is slow because of the network. Can I built a progress bar, I put hour-glass but not helpful, the users are not patient and clicking around and make MS Access 2010 to give them application not responding.

Pass-through query looks like this:

```
Select a.Number,
       a.Letter,
       a.description,
       a.place
       a.timechange
       s.location           
       from tableA 
              join location s
              on a.place = s.location
              where a.place like '02 D[0-7]%' and a.timechange > '2014-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

4-minutes is not due to network latency, unless you have a *really* slow nets (are you using a modem) or the query size is very large.  You might consider trying to make the query faster.

```
Select a.Number, a.Letter, a.description, a.place, a.timechange
       s.location           
from tableA join
     location s
     on a.place = s.location
where a.place like '02 D[0-7]%' and a.timechange > '2014-01-01';
```

I would suggest an index on `tableA(place, timechange)` and on `location(location)`.  Optimizing the query might be a better solution than making the users' waits more pleasant.

Comment: The query should return 15373 records. Its not the place to brag about my location. I thought I could write you a personnel message but I couldn't found an option. I`m read only user on the SQL so I could not change anything even If want but trust me I have very slow internet and the SQL is provided from a branded company.